# Applying for job on mobile the text field is too thin

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Hope this gets to the stack team, when you're applying for a job on mobile there's a field to introduce yourself, the text field is too narrow and I can't resize it on chrome

[image]

Comment: This should actually be posted on Meta SO, since Jobs is SO-specific.

Comment: That's not available on the app, just wanted this to reach them so they know

Comment: that font made me kick a kitten.

Comment: Can't you drag the dot in the lower-right-hand corner and increase the size of the text box? Also you may want to include at least the OS (I'd assume Android due to the font change).

Comment: can't get that drag to work, it's android 7 on chrome

Comment: Programming Q&A site with hundreds of senior level web developers isn't completely responsive. Irony.

Comment: I can understand the post anyway but I reckon it is worth pointing out 'thin' and 'narrow' are the wrong words here as they relate to width. 'Short' or 'small' are probably more appropriate as they relate to height (ok, small isn't _strictly_ height but it is still closer in this context than thin or narrow you pedantics :P ).

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland *pedants. (Sorry, I had to, after that setup.)

Comment: Ha! quiet alright @maxathousand, I _knew_ pedantics didn't sound right when I wrote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix just went out for this giving a whole bunch more space to tell companies why you are amazing.

Thank you for pointing this out!

[image: screen shot of new textarea sizing]